# Remove hash from url in vue js

Tags: iis, vue.js, .net-core, web-config, vue-router

So I try to remove # from url. Currently I am getting like http://localhost:2161/#/. Just I want http://localhost:2161/ like this.

Have tried by changing [as said by vuejs router document](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-hisQory-mode) 
and [in `web.config` file](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations) .

But getting the exception in console,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

in  this following line in `web.config` file.

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the #. If you would remove the # the browser/server would try to get the file/page at that url - which doesnt exist. Because vue works with a virtual dom, this means it will inject the pages into the current loaded webpage.

If you want to use urls like in wordpress - the "clean" url's you need to do url rewriting in .htaccess

Comment: but the [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-hisQory-mode) said we can remove the # symbol from url by using history mode. also I am using `IIS url rewrite plugin` as they mentioned in doc